# Excel VBA Skip row of code if runtime is too long

Tags: vba, excel

I need a method to skip a row of code if it takes too long to run. This is a single row, any code.  For example, this row:

```
managerAlias = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetExchangeUserManager.Alias
```

This takes 0.2 sec if the data is available from outlook server. But data is not available, it takes a long time >30sec. I use on "error resume next" but have to wait for the error to happen. So the general question is how do I skip a line if that line takes more than 5 seconds to execute?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't something that's possible in VBA. And as your question is essentially asking for the community to provide you with code rather than solving a specific coding issue with *your* code, I'm voting to close it as off-topic / too broad (because explaining a working solution to do that would require something like an entire blog post).

Comment: Don't close this. It has been asked before for other lines of code that block execution for too long and isn't easy to do (if it's at all possilble). I suspect a solution might utilize a combination Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler in combination with something like Application.OnTime.

Answer (score -2):

You could set that code in a loop so that it will skip past if a certain time elapses.

No tested but

```
myTime = now() + timevalue("00:00:03")
Do while managerAlias = null AND mytime < now()  
    managerAlias = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetExchangeUserManager.Alias
loop
```

if you want less than a second, multiply the timevalue by less than 1
(Timevalue ("00:00:01") * 0.2)

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. The issue is that calling the Alias functon 1 time may take 30 seconds before that function throws a timeout error